# Why is Date class in base R backed by a double

Tags: r, date, optimization

The Date class in base R is backed by a double:

```
> dput(Sys.Date())
structure(18095, class = "Date")
> class(unclass(Sys.Date()))
[1] "numeric"
```

Why not by an integer? That would save half the memory (4 bytes per date) and seems to work in simple cases at least:

```
> structure(18095L, class = "Date")
[1] "2019-07-18"
```

#### Edit:

Comments mention using fractional dates. I'm wary of using fractional dates in general but R's behaviour might definitely not be what you expect:

```
> as.POSIXct(structure(18095.5, class = "Date"))
[1] "2019-07-18 14:00:00 CEST"
```

I can see why that is the correct result but still.

Comment: Just a guess, hours, minutes, seconds are in decimals, so we need double?

Comment: I considered this, but then you're not talking dates anymore but times for which we have the `POSIX` classes.

Comment: Interesting question. I think you're much more likely to get an answer from the [R-devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) though.

Comment: Yes, hh:mm:ss is not used in date, but is used to determine the current date. Interesting question, would like to see a better explanation.

Comment: This is basically why data.table created `IDateTime`. Re base R, the answer is usually "*historical reasons*".

Comment: You can actually have partial dates stored, e.g. `mean(c(structure(18095L, class = "Date"), structure(18096L, class = "Date")))` will be `18095.5`, even though the fractions are ignored by the `print` method. With integer representation this would not be possible.

Comment: Interestingly even though the underlying type is a double, there seems to be a chance for integer overflow [as mentioned here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/as-Date-Inf-displays-as-NA-but-is-actually-Inf-td4755820.html#a4755835). Try: `as.Date(2^31, origin = "1970-01-01")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled on [this post](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1738#issuecomment-513406846) in the data.table issue tracker. There Matt Dowle mentions that R core told him that double is indeed used to support fractional dates and to ensure that the `Date` class is closed under operations such as `mean()`. I don't think that is a great idea, luckily for people like me there now is [`IDateTime`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.2/topics/IDateTime) :)